# Show that $f_n\to f$ in the norm $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.  Define
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if }|x|\leq n\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Show that $f_n\to f$ i.n.

This seems really obvious, so I'm not sure how to go about actually showing it.  If $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $|x|\leq n$, then, as $n\to\infty$, $f_n\to f$, obviously.  Unless I'm missing something.

The other thing is the "i.n.", convergent "in norm".  Can anyone explain how to do that?  Would it just be what I outlined above?  Or something else?

Comment: When you say $f_n\rightarrow f$, obviously, you should specify in what sense. In this case $f_n\rightarrow f$, obviously pointwise. The claim in this exercise however is to show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L_1$-norm, i.e. $\int |f_n-f|dx\rightarrow 0$. How would you show that? (Remember that $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$)

Answer (score 1):

Convergent "in norm" means 
$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}}|f_n-f|d\mu\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$.
Since $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[-n,n]}|f|d\mu=\int_{\Bbb{R}}|f|d\mu<\infty
$$
Given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $N$ such that for any $n>N$
$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]}|f|d\mu<\epsilon
$$
So
$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}}|f_n-f|d\mu=\int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]}|f|d\mu<\epsilon
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Define $f_n = f\chi_{[-n,n]}$, which is the same as your definition. Then $|f_n(x)| \le |f(x)|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $|f_n-f| \le 2|f|$ and $\lim_n|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$ for all $x$. Therefore, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem,
$$
             \lim_n \|f_n-f\| = \lim_n\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n-f|dx = 0.
$$